# openshift install custom cartridge from github to application

Tags: python, request, web.py, openshift

I would like to install some libraries from github, one of which is [python-request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/), the other would be webpy, but stay at this example:

On their site they offer various ways to install it:

1. `$ pip install requests`
2. `git clone git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git`
3. `$ python setup.py install`

For me the third option seems to be the easiest however I cannot run python on local machine with taking effects on the server.

I also tried to add it by url on the GUI of OpenShift, but it throws an error that it is incorrect.

How can I add this library to my existing OpenShift application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add this library to your OpenShift application.

You also have several options:

1. Start a simple application and include these libraries as part of your git repository

   1. Note: this is not the same as what you were trying to do with **git clone**
2. Use the setup.py configuration file to include libraries using pip.

   1. see the [python flask example, it includes flask and markupsave](https://github.com/openshift/flask-example/blob/master/setup.py#L9) from pip

These are the two best options that you have.